# Trouble with custom typefaces

Tags: java, android, android-typeface

Recently I've decided to update my old app, but  I get an error that `native typeface cannot be made`. I didn't get it before. To test whether it's some glitch in that particular project, I created a new one, where I implement custom typeface, but the error's the same.

Here my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Typeface MontBold;
Typeface AsapBold;
TextView txt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf");
    AsapBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Asap-Bold.otf");
    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt1.setTypeface(AsapBold);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Fonts location

[image]

Logcat errors

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a typo here. You're providing wrong font name while creating from Assets. It should be "Montserrat-Bold.otf".

Comment: Thanks. How could I miss this? It did the trick in the new project, no luck with the old one though.